# How to use if else statement in JQuery to execute respective __doPostBack statement

Tags: jquery

i want that same JQuery function should execute for two controls. How to use `if else statement based on class name selector in JQuery` that will decide that which control has trigger it so that either `__doPostBack('<%=checkbox1.UniqueID%>', "")` or `__doPostBack('<%=checkbox2.UniqueID%>', "")` should execute.

I have used following statements but nothing happen although `JQuery` runs for each `chechbox`

```
if ((chk).hasClass('ab1'))
     __doPostBack('<%=checkbox1.UniqueID%>', "");
 else
     __doPostBack('<%=checkbox2.UniqueID%>', "");
```

here `chk` is the respective `checkbox` that called `JQuery` function

**Edited**

checkbox click function

```
OnClick="return shakeel(this);"
```

Following register the two checkboxes

```
<script>
    function shakeel(chk) {
        $(function () {
            $('.ab1, .ab2').on('click', DiscountAtLast(chk));
            });         
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [`$.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: Is `chk` a jQuery object? Show the definition of `chk`.

Comment: OnClick="return shakeel(this);"       <script>
    function shakeel(chk) {
        $(function () {
            $('.ab1, .ab2').on('click', DiscountAtLast(chk));
            });         
        return true;
    }
</script>